# Android studio error R.java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an error in the R.java file when I open android studio 3.0.

Here is the error:

[image: Here is the error]

```
public static final int Both are incorrect=0x7f080002;
```

when I try to edit it or delete this line it keeps saying that:

> "Generated source files should not be edited, The changes will be lost when the sources are regenerated"

Comment: You should never edit `R.java`, as it says, it's a generated file to help you access resources. Why do you want to edit it in the first place?

Comment: my app isn't working i cant do anything even the activity isn't working !! i cant have successful build !! i don't know why

Answer (score 2):

The error happens because you have a ***wrong*** **id** in your layout. You can't use a space for id name in a view.

You need to check for the following id in your layout:

```
android:id="@+id/Both are incorrect"
```

Then remove or change the space, you can use underscore:

```
android:id="@+id/both_are_incorrect"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit R.java file because this file is auto-generated by compiler. And your problem is you can never use space in "id" & variable as well so first change your ID (it's better if you rename id using refactor) and rebuild you project hopefully it will work... 
Happy coding...  :)

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly occurs due to the change in your **layout.xml** file

try to check your id's in layout.xml file as

- id's should not contain spaces
- id's should not start always with numbers
- id's should not be repeated
- id's should start with @+ or +

try to clean your project from menu or sync with gradle files.